# TEAMCITY - Update build status

Tags: rest, teamcity

As part of our continuous integration system, our automation runs several tests when a TeamCity build is SUCCESSFUL. It downloads the latest build and runs a set of automated tests. If the tests fail, we would like to make that build as FAILURE, even though the build process was successful, the build itself has a bug so we would like to change the (enum) BuildStatus.

The Sharp2City API only implements the get accessor, there is no set for any object.

I am aware that according to TeamCity:
***By default, the permission to change build status is granted to Project Administrator.***

Is there a way to set the BUILD STATUS via C# code?

Comment: Are your automated tests being run by a C# app that you've written yourself?

Comment: Yes, we have a separate application that downloads the build on another machine (when a new build is successfully built) and runs tests in specific environment. The tests cannot be run by TeamCity